# como determinar o percentil que um determinado valor possui em uma amostra no R

Tags: r

suponhamos que eu tenha uma amostra em forma de vetor

`x <-c(2,3,68,253,1,35,3,35,01,24,04,36,254,2,28,12,4,54,66,775,6,45,33,68,71)`

eu sei que se eu fizer o comando:

`quantile(x, 0.75)` o R me retorna o percentil P75.

mas eu gostaria de saber por exemplo em qual percentil está localizado o elemento de valor 35 do meu conjunto x?

O R responderia uma questão dessa? existe um inverso do comando quantile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe uma função inversa de `quantile` mas não é difícil obter o percentil de um qualquer valor `x0`.

```
x0 <- 35
```

Primeiro determina-se com `findInterval` onde está `x0` no vetor `x` ordenado. Para ter quantis, divide-se pelo comprimento do vetor.

```
onde1 <- findInterval(x0, sort(x))/length(x)
quantile(x, onde1)
# 60% 
#35.4
```

`x0` deverá corresponder a um quantil abaixo de 60%, portanto abre-se o intervalo à esquerda.

```
onde2 <- findInterval(x0, sort(x), left.open = TRUE)/length(x)
quantile(x, onde2)
#  52% 
#33.96
```

Fechar o intervalo à direita não serviria de nada:

```
onde3 <- findInterval(x0, sort(x), rightmost.closed = TRUE)/length(x)
quantile(x, onde3)
# 60% 
#35.4
```

Agora calcula-se o valor pedido com `approx`.

```
qq <- quantile(x, probs = c(onde3, onde1))
xqq <- unname(qq)
yqq <- as.numeric(sub("%", "", names(qq)))

approx(xqq, yqq, xout = x0)
#$x
#[1] 35
#
#$y
#[1] 57.77778
```